# subscript and superscript in Lyx leave large gaps in onscreen editor

Tags: lyx, subscripts, superscripts

When I insert superscript or subscript formatting using the Insert>Formatting menu in Lyx, it leaves a large gap between the sub/super-scripted text and the preceding text. This does not happen when using math mode for sub/superscipting - only when using the formatting menu commands ("script-insert superscript" and "script-insert subscript", respectively).  Note that this behaviour only affects the onscreen editing display - the rendered pdf output is fine.  But it is rather irritating during editing, particularly when working on technical documents with a lot of units that have superscripts and subscripts. Is there any way to fix this behaviour so that the onscreen display in the editor does not insert these gaps? I am using Lyx 2.1.4

An example of this behaviour is shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: I think this kind of thing is better reported at http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome It looks like something that isn't managed by some setting here or there, so not really something we're likely to be able to answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The described behaviour is caused by setting `LeftMargin` in the document settings `Local Layout`.

This is because `InsetLayouts` (which control the layout of sub/superscripts, among other things) inherit the global margin settings, with no possibility to adjust the margin to their own values (missing feature).

A bug report ticket has been raised at http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10177 to the effect that `LeftMargin` and `RightMargin`, when specified on top level, should only apply to the main text.